# cannot load a new theme in magento

Tags: magento2, theme, configuration

i have tried to change my theme and when i did i get following error

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Could not   read config file

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Could not   read config file
#0 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\vendor\magento\framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem.p hp(123): Magento\Framework\Config\FileResolver->get('view.xml', 'global')
#1 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\vendor\magento\framework\Config\View.php(233): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->read('global')
#2 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\vendor\magento\framework\Config\View.php(213): Magento\Framework\Config\View->read()
#3 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\vendor\magento\framework\Config\View.php(90): Magento\Framework\Config\View->initData()
#4 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Helper\Image.php(833): Magento\Framework\Config\View->getVarValue('Magento_Catalog', 'product_image_w...')
#5 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\vendor\magento\module-checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar.php(81): Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image->getFrame()
#6 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\var\generation\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar\Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar->getImageHtmlTemplate()
#7 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\vendor\magento\module-checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar.php(70): Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar\Interceptor->getImageHtmlTemplate()
#8 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar->getConfig()
#9 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\var\generation\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar\Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getConfig', Array, Array)
#10 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart\minicart.phtml(46): Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar\Interceptor->getConfig()
#11 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\vendor\magento\framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php.php(59): include('C:\\xampp\\apps\\m...')
#12 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar\Interceptor), 'C:/xampp/apps/m...', Array)
```

Comment: have u tried to create own theme  or using purchase theme

Comment: i was trying to create my own theme

Comment: please share your theme structure